# Occ cx admin auth issue

Tags: oracle-commerce-cloud

I was trying to run dev occ env usually for the very first time it ask for sign in cred where i put admin , admin for both username and password but today something happened which i'm not aware about. These cred not working, could anyone knows how to debug or resolve this.

I tried with admin, admin cred but it's not working for me
[this is the signin box which i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZQCr.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.